# Ubuntu 17.10 - ALT + Tab swaps between workspaces

Tags: workspaces, 17.10, application-switcher

Since I updated to Ubuntu 17.10, I have noticed that when I try to switch windows, using `ALT + Tab`, it shows me not only the windows in my current workspace but all the other ones.

Before the upgrade, this was not the behavior of task switching, and I actually miss how it was before.

Is there any way that I can recover the old behavior?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true`

Comment: That worked. Make it a solution, and I will accept it